# Couldn't get back to my Ubuntu with my password

Tags: password, security

I woke up this morning, and I couldn't get back to my Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS. I had to change root password using Vultr.com's documentation on it. I checked the access log (/var/log/access.log) and it is full of IP addresses and attempts. Maybe someone managed to get in?

If so, how can I protect myself from similar situations?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Go back to bed ... or update tour question with the offending lines from /val/log/access.log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by reinstalling your OS after backing up desired data.  Completely disconnect it from the Internet while doing this.  Post re-install here's a simple check list.

1. Set strong passwords.
2. [Configure your firewall](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/firewall.html) (Ubuntu doesn't configure a firewall initially by default).

Beyond that, there are numerous guides on securing servers which directly apply to Desktop Linux.  Check out [openstack-ansible-security](https://github.com/openstack/openstack-ansible-security).